# Turn narrative entries into scores in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

So I have a dataset and one of the features is Proximity, there are three options: near, medium, far. I want to turn these into scores so would it be better to assign the value 3 for near, 2 for medium, 1 for far. Or would I make separate columns for near, medium, far and assign 1 and 0 depending on the proximity id originally?

I plan on calculating the VIF of the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to do this;

1. Use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html);

```
df['proximity_code'] = pandas.Categorical(df['Proximity'])
```

Now the data look similar but is stored categorically. To capture the category codes:

```
df['proximity_code'] = df.proximity_code.cat.codes
```

2. Create a function that solves your problem by hand;

```
def proximity_to_code(input_string):
    if input_string == 'near':
        return 3
    elif input_string == 'medium':
        return 2
    elif input_string == 'far':
        return 1

    # if input_string is na 
    else: 
        return 0
```

Apply the function to your column;

```
df['proximity_code'] = df['Proximity'].apply(proximity_to_code)
```

Comment: Thank you! much appreciated